# Mysql Insert dropping the last two rows

Tags: php, mysql

As part of a site I'm developing I am getting all the current data breaches available on 'Have I been pwned' via a PHP script. I can get all the breaches using the site's API at which time there are 104. I have attempted inserting them all into a database table, however the last 2 are being dropped for some reason so the total rows inserted are only 102 not 104. There are no constraints in my table and I've checked for mysql errors as well as used SHOW WARNINGS and still nothing.

Has anyone any idea why this would be happening? It has occurred before, however this was due to a constraint on the Varchar limit so changed it to Text and that solved the issue until now. I'm using a count of the JSON array being brought in from the API and the count is 104 so it must be Mysql that is at fault here. Any ideas anybody?

```
$fs = file_get_contents('https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breaches/', false, $context)
$fs = json_decode($file, true);
$count = count($fs);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
                $title = mysql_real_escape_string($fs[$i]['Title']);
                $name = mysql_real_escape_string($fs[$i]['Name']);
                $domain = mysql_real_escape_string($fs[$i]['Domain']);
                $breachdate = mysql_real_escape_string($fs[$i]['BreachDate']);
                $adddate = mysql_real_escape_string($fs[$i]['AddedDate']);
                //$ad_date = explode("T", $adddate);
                //$add_date = $ad_date[0];
                //$add_time = rtrim($ad_date[1], "Z");
                //$add_time = $ad_date[1];
                $pwncount = mysql_real_escape_string($fs[$i]['PwnCount']);
                $desc = mysql_real_escape_string($fs[$i]['Description']);
                //$dc = count($fs[$i]['DataClasses']);
                $dca = implode(',',$fs[$i]['DataClasses']);
                $isver = mysql_real_escape_string($fs[$i]['IsVerified']);
                $issens = mysql_real_escape_string($fs[$i]['IsSensitive']);
                $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO breaches (Title, Name, Domain, AddedDate, BreachDate, PwnCount, Descript, DataClasses, IsVerified, IsSensitive) VALUES ('$title','$name','$domain','$adddate','$breachdate','$pwncount','$desc','$dca','$isver','$issens')");
                //echo '<p>Title: '.$title.'</p>';
                //echo '<p>Data Classes: '.$dca.'</p>';
            }
```

the output of $count is as expected 104 since there are 104 items in the returned JSON array. Only 102 records are reaching the database table, no constraints.

Comment: Post some code, show us what you've done so far, then we will be able to help you.

Comment: I am flagging this question as unclear what you're asking, please consider revising it.

Comment: Unclear? I've been as crystal clear as possible here. I've already stated I'm getting every breach from the HIBP API of which there are 104. The output is in JSON. I'm taking this JSON output, running a PHP loop then inserting what should be all 104 breaches into a database table in mysql. How is that unclear?

Comment: @olibiaz I'm not sure how to post code in comments, however the PHP basically gets all 104 breaches from the HIBP API. The out from that is in JSON but this is easily gone through with a for loop and then inserted into the database table in mysql. My question is simple, why would it be dropping the last 2 rows?

Comment: Yes its unclear, without code, its hard figure out your problem, even if i have no doubt its very clear for you. Please update your question for posting code. Not in comment. Post your input, your code and then it should be easier for us to help you.

Comment: @olibiaz question has been updated to include the code now.

Comment: In your json have you spotted the lines that are not inserted? It is possible that some information/fields are missing that match a non null column in your mysql?

Comment: Yeah the lines that start with // are ones that I decided not to include for time being. All the columns have been set to allow null values except for the primary key which is AUTO INCREMENT. It's definitely nothing to do with the JSON output. There are 104 in the JSON array as said, only 102 are getting to the table, there must be an explanation. There hasn't been any errors at all.

Answer (score 0):

add some error checking to the sql after the $sql = mysql_query line

```
if (!$sql) {
    print_r($fs[$i]);
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Tried this already and nothing happened. There hasn't been any errors, there are simply 2 out of the 104 in the JSON array output that are just not getting to the table. It really is baffling me because there is no way to find out why unless there is a SQL statement I can try other than SHOW WARNINGS.

Comment: Just to double check. Output all the sql statements to the screen and run them manually. You can run them all in one go as long as you put a ; at the end of each statement. It could be that the 2 returned results have a ' in them, which could possibly cause an issue

Comment: There is only one sql statement and that is one to INSERT and there are no errors coming from it at all. Remember this is being done through a PHP script. There is no manual way to do it because I need the JSON output first before I put it into the table. There is just no reason that it should be dropping 2 rows and it seems there is no way of finding out why it is doing so.

Comment: Yes, but you can get the sql query from the php script, output it to the screen and then run that query on your database manually in PHPMyAdmin. There are plenty of reasons that could be causing it. You need to try to debug it and rule out possibilities. How bout posting the json response to your question first and we can look at that.

Comment: The JSON response would be the entire output of 104 breaches, way too much to put here. When you say run it on my database manually, how? Where would it get the information from the store in the database, an insert query would just come back with an error, makes no sense. I'm not massively one with database stuff by the way, I only know so much.

Comment: Have you used phpMyAdmin before? It's a graphical way to interact with the database. If you post the json then someone can run the script on their own server and test it out and try and find the problem.

Comment: Also post your database table structure if you can

Comment: Well I found out where the issue was. I identified which of the 2 breaches wasn't being inserted into the table. There was something within the JSON output that mysql wasn't liking so it was skipping both of them without any error output. I changed the $dca to $dca = mysql_real_escape_string($dca) and bingo! It worked, it has now put all 104 breaches into my database table. Thank you and thanks to everyone else that tried to help. Sorry for being a pain.

Comment: @Dave glad you got it sorted